# Antlr4 grammar requires me to use setInterpreter

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4

When i set up a grammar with antlr4, and generated it i see the following line throughout the parser

```
_errHandler.sync(this);
```

Which in turn, does

```
getInterpreter()
```

and then calls methods on it. By default this returns null, and thus parsing throws NPEs.

I glomed together `something` that gets around this

```
myparser.setInterpreter(new ParserATNSimulator(myparser, myparser.getATN(), mylexer.getInterpreter().decisionToDFA,
                new PredictionContextCache()));
```

But I'm certain that is wrong. The odd thing is I don't see any examples address this requirement, so I'm wondering what i have done wrong that this even needs to be done.

Interesting TestRig works fine, w/o the setInterpreter line, here's what i'm doing:

```
PelLexer pl = new PelLexer(CharStreams.fromString(s));
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(pl);

SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
String clsName = Parser.class.getPackage().getName() + ".eval.Eval" + Math.abs(r.nextLong());
PelParser pp = new PelParser(tokens, clsName);

pp.setBuildParseTree(false);

// pp.setInterpreter(new ParserATNSimulator(pp, pp.getATN(), pl.getInterpreter().decisionToDFA, new PredictionContextCache()));

pp.addErrorListener(new PELErrorListener());

pp.blockStatements();

byte[] clzData = pp.getClassBytes();

PELClassLoader pcl = AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<PELClassLoader>() {

    @Override
    public PELClassLoader run() {
        return new PELClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    }
});

pcl.addClass(clsName, clzData);

Class<Evaluable> c = (Class<Evaluable>) pcl.loadClass(clsName);
return c.newInstance();
```

Comment: Why are you doing this at all?  What error or problem prompted you to attempt this?

Comment: As stated. without adding the setInterpreter line, the parser throws NPEs because the interpreter is null.

Comment: Odd.  I've never seen that behavior before.  Are you sure all your classes are getting generated?  Does sample input lex and parse using TestRig?  That's usually the first thing I try whenever I have any kind of error.

Comment: yes TestRig works fine, in fact TestRig works w/o the need for the setInterpreter line. I've updated the post with how i'm failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer.

When you add a constructor to your parser, you **DON'T** want to call

```
super(tokens);
```

You want to call

```
this(tokens);
```

As the default constructor created in your parser does

```
public PelParser(TokenStream input) {
    super(input);
    _interp = new ParserATNSimulator(this,_ATN,_decisionToDFA,_sharedContextCache);
}
```